# Story ID: U.S. soldier mistaken for football star in Japan

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

An acquaintance is trying to find a short story she read some years ago (I am sorry she could not identify how far). She thinks she read it in Reader's Digest, or in a collection of stories from it.

In this story, a U.S. soldier serving in Japan (I don't know if it's set during the occupation or later) has a name similar to that of a well-known NFL (?) player, and is mistaken for him. Somehow he is unable to explain the error, and is invited to display his prowess in a scrimmage. He tells his plight to his teammates. They tell him that once he gets the ball, just close his eyes and run in the right direction, and they will block everyone out of his way.